# How to add two decimal numbers

Tags: android-studio

I have three edit texts in which if I put decimal numbers like 23.5 +23.5  and click calculate the app crashes and if I put 235000 +235000 it gives correct results what should be the correct codes for decimal number ,I am new to all this please forgive me for my mistakes`

```js
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        double tys=Integer.parseInt(Tys.getText().toString());
        double lys=Integer.parseInt(Lys.getText().toString());
        double tgt=Integer.parseInt(Tgt.getText().toString());
        double sum=((int)tys-lys)/lys*100;
        DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
// dblVariable is a number variable and not a String in this case
        GrowthResult.setText(precision.format(sum)+"%");

        double sum2 =((int)tys/tgt)*100;
        achievementResult.setText(precision.format(sum2)+"%");
        double sum3 =((int)tys-lys);
        JumpResult.setText(precision.format(sum3));
```

`

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Codes please. No we wont steal your super brilliant ideas or codes.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

You can take data types like float type.then you will get correct answer

float a;
float b;

Edit text data parse in float type then you will get correct answer